# What is the "Image Unique ID" EXIF field?

Tags: metadata

What is the **Image Unique ID** in Exif info? what is it used for?!

It seems each system could use its own method, so is it still unique between different systems?

Searching online I was able to find this information:

**Stolen Camera Finder**
Apparently [stolen camera finders](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/digitalcameras/find-your-lost-or-stolen-camera-with-free-online-tools/5538) use this Unique ID and other information to find stolen cameras.

**Shutter Counts**
Some forums suggests that Image Unique ID also contains shutter counts: [Determining Shutter Actuations on an M8](http://www.l-camera-forum.com/leica-forum/leica-m8-forum/35415-determining-shutter-actuations-m8.html) and [this one](http://www.rangefinderforum.com/forums/showthread.php?t=91514), so it's not always a random number.

**Definition according to the [Exif.org](http://www.exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF) website:**
"This tag indicates an identifier assigned uniquely to each image. It is recorded as an ASCII string equivalent to hexadecimal notation and 128-bit fixed length."

Also see [this similar question on another forum](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=2601.0).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the length of the field as defined in Exif 2.2, it appears to be a field to hold a GUID (or globally unique identifier) that should uniquely identify that particular picture from all other pictures.  It should be chosen at random and based on the size of the available address space (128 bits) a collision is extremely unlikely for the foreseeable future.

Comment: AJ Henderson - you are thinking in the long term :-). If everyone on earth had a camera and took one photo a second, if a 128 bit binary number was used truly randomly then over a 100 year period there would be about a billion billion billion + unique numbers available PER SECOND per photo :-). ||| 2^128 / 8765 h/y / 3600 s/h / E10 people ~= 1E19. E11 people (!) = 1E18.

Comment: @RusselMcMahon - true, but GUIDs are supposed to be unique across more than just photos.  Camera's are hardly going to be the fastest consumer of GUIDs and eventually you will get collisions, but the chances of a practical, meaningful collision are effectively null for a very, very long time even so.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - Your math isn't working too well for me. Based on current population, 2.24E17 GUIDs would be used per year based on all people shooting once per second (365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 7097962000). That would require 1.52E21 years to consume all possible combinations (2^128/[previous result]). Our planet is going to be long relegated to space ash before we exhaust the set... having been consumed by our sun some 380 billion years prior.

Comment: @AJHenderson - It goes well beyond foreseeable...

Comment: JoanneC: foreseeable is a relative term.  We honestly can't really guess when a collision in the full set will be hit since it also requires a level of randomness that computers fail to reach in most cases and 1 guid generation per person per second is a VERY low estimate of what current usage probably is and certainly is going forward.  I would expect that we will eventually be talking guid generation on the orders of tens of thousands per person per second if they become a widely used system of identifying records.

Comment: JoanneC: we also don't nearly need to consume all of them, just a sufficient portion to make collisions likely.  That is a very small subset of the overall address space.  Practically, it doesn't really matter if a photo shares a guid with a IP routing record though, so it doesn't really matter, but the principal of the set will eventually be invalid, though by that time we will simply be able to up the address space significantly as it will still be a very, very long time.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates which still probably means that there is really no need to worry that we'll have a duplication issue in Earth's lifespan...

Comment: From the wikipedia link - "generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100 years, the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about 50%"  That's not that far in to the future if we were going with the example of every person taking a photo every second.  I'm not saying it's a real problem and this is really more of a question for Math or something similar.  They are still practically useful, but they do eventually break down with enough use.

Comment: @AJHenderson But is it always random?! I read somewhere that in some cameras the number also contains the shutter count or camera's serial number.

Comment: @Omne - it is possible in some cases it could be used for some other form of unique identifier (of which camera serial and shutter count would be unique).  EXIF data is largely open to how the manufacturer wants to implement it, but the field is setup to be able to support GUIDs.